# how to redirect to a requested page instead of default page after login

Tags: asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication

I able to redirect the user to the home.aspx page after every successful login, but I dont want to do like that.For every successful login ,i m sending a link. So if they click that particular link or button i want them to be re-directed to the login page and after successful login i want to them to view the requested page.

I am trying to do like this.But its nt working.Where ll i grab the requesetd link and ll store it in `Request.Params["ReturnUrl"]`??

```
if(Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] != null)
{
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.text, false);
}
else
{
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthcookie(txtUserName.text, false);
  Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks & Regards

Madhu

Comment: This is not `asp-classic`.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart - I think it's pretty grim how many people *assume* that ASP.NET is Classic ASP! It honestly shows a certain ignorance to the subject matter.  It's like comparing JavaScript to Java...